# match symbols + and * in a regular expression using replace-regexp in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

Seems like a very basic question but how to catch the characters `*` and / or `+` in a regular expression using `replace-regexp` (or `re-bulding`) ?
Problem is, if I am not mistaken, that `+` and `*` are used respectively to match at least one or zero or more of the previous character.

To be more specific, I would like to match something like `[^*+]` i.e any character other than `*` and `+`.

I can find the answer anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use these characters inside square brackets, then they are treated as characters, not the repeaters. The only special care should be taken about `-` character - because it's used to specify ranges of characters, it should be first one if it's used in the range search, like, `[-+]`, or `[^-+]`.

if you're using these characters outside of the range operator, you will need to escape it with backslash, like, `\+`, or `\\+` if it's in the code that execute regular expression.

More information about regular expression syntax you can find on [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression), and in [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html).

Comment: I probably miss this part of the doc. Otherwise what do you exactly mean by "if it's in the code that execute regular expression" ?

Comment: There is a difference between how backslashes are encoded in the regular expressions themselves when you execute them directly, versus backslashes in the strings that contain regular expressions, because backslashes are used also to escape other characters, then they will need to be escaped themselves, for example: https://github.com/alexott/cql-mode/blob/master/cql-mode.el#L26